# Is it possible to set the text alignment for a Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonEditBox control?

Tags: c#, vsto

Is there a way to set the alignment of a `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonEditBox` control?

For example, I would like to center the text in the `SkipEditControl` defined in the code below.

```
this.SkipEditControl.Label = "Skip:";
this.SkipEditControl.Name = "SkipEditControl";
this.SkipEditControl.OfficeImageId = "ConditionalFormattingBottomNItems";
this.SkipEditControl.ShowImage = true;
this.SkipEditControl.SuperTip = " 0 - Take every row.\n 1 - Take 1 row and skip 1 row.\n 2 - Take 1 row and skip 2 rows.\n N - Take 1 row and skip N rows.";
this.SkipEditControl.Text = "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12))